# center image vertically in div and float elements to right, display inline-block not working

Tags: html, css

html

```
    <div id="navBar">
    <div class="navBarStyles">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.www8-hp.com/us/en/images/i/header-footer/caas-hf-v3/hp-logo-pr.gif"/></a>
        <ul class="iconStyles">
            <li><a href="#">u</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">z</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
    #navBar{
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: "opensans-semibold";
    font-size: 1em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0088FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 100px;
}
#navBar a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: .8;
}
#navBar a:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
#navBar .navBarStyles img{
    display: inline-block;       /*this style is not working */
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

#navBar .navBarStyles .iconStyles li{
    float: right;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWce7/)

What I want to do here is center image vertically in my navigation bar, but when I use `display: inline-block;` it seems not working. I tried `float: left;` but then the image is not centered vertically.

Comment: you want the logo on the left side and the menu on the right site... and the menu vertical align with the logo?

Comment: the logo vertical aligned to the background. The buttons get aligned with vertical-align, only the logo is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. What about this: [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eteHuBU/2)

HTML:

```
<div id="navBar">    
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://www.www8-hp.com/us/en/images/i/header-footer/caas-hf-v3/hp-logo-pr.gif"/>
    </a>    
    <div class="navBarStyles">      
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="i-icon">u</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-icon">z</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #navBar{
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: "opensans-semibold";
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #0088FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#navBar a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: .8;
}
#navBar a:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}

#logo {

  display: inline-block;
}

#logo img  {

  margin: 0 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navBarStyles {

  float: right;
  line-height: 1.9em;
}
.navBarStyles ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I don't think its vertically centered perfectly.

Comment: but if I add line-height, the text doesn't align anymore to the height of the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using table

HTML

```
<div id="navBar">
<table class="navBarStyles"><tr>
    <td id="esq"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.www8-hp.com/us/en/images/i/header-footer/caas-hf-v3/hp-logo-pr.gif"/></a>
    </td>
    <td id="dir">
    <ul class="iconStyles">
        <li><a href="#" class="i-icon">u</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-icon">z</a></li>
    </ul>
    </td>
    </tr></table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navBar{
 max-width: 960px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: "opensans-semibold";
 font-size: 1em;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #0088FF;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 100px;
}
#navBar a{
color: #FFFFFF;
opacity: .8;
}
#navBar a:hover{
opacity: 1;
}
#navBar .navBarStyles img{
display: inline-block;      
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

#navBar .navBarStyles .iconStyles li{
float: right;
padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

#esq {text-alignment:left;}

#dir {text-alignment:right;}

.navBarStyles {width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jQuery:

```
<script>
w = window.innerWidth;
h = window.innerHeight;
$('#id').css('height', h - 100);
$('#id').css('margin-top', 50);
$('#id').css('width', w - 100);
$('#id').css('margin-left', 50);
</script>
```

With 50 is half of 100 above there and 100 is the total distance between the div or picture with "#id" and the browser height and width.

You can use jQuery to find the height of a div too:

h = $("#myDiv").height();

Answer (score 0):

The `image` is vertically centered aligned to the `parent div` which is the background, the `links` depends on the position of the image that is why it added space below the image which makes the image looks not vertically centered. I added a `padding` to the `top` of the image equal to the space the links added in which, to avoid major re-coding.

Check this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XG7Xr/3/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: No it is not. If you add the style `height: 500px;` to `#navbar` you will see that the image is not in the middle.

Comment: Yes. I mentioned that it is because of the links, if you remove the whole <ul> tag from the HTML code along with the padding-top in #navBar .navBarStyles img which I added to make the spaces equal, regardless of whatever margins added, the vertical alignment of the image is in the middle.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the inline style:

```
    style="vertical-align:middle"
```

The result would look like:

```
    <img src="http://www.www8-hp.com/us/en/images/i/header-footer/caas-hf-v3/hp-logo-pr.gif" style="vertical-align:middle" />
```

You can also create an image class for it as well, the in-line style is just an example.